# How to give user defined Password Open XML SDK

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

I am using Open XML SDK for creating excel files.

I want to protect them with a password and this password will be user defined.
To protect the sheet I am using the following code.

```
SheetProtection sheetProtection = new();
                sheetProtection.Password = "CC1A";
                sheetProtection.Sheet = true;
                sheetProtection.Objects = true;
                sheetProtection.Scenarios = true;

                worksheetPart.Worksheet.InsertAfter(sheetProtection, worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First());
```

And to protect the cells which I want, I am just adding the following lines into their cell format

```
ApplyProtection = styleKey.IsProtected,
            Protection = styleKey.IsProtected ? new Protection() { Locked = true } : new Protection() { Locked = false }
```

Everything is working fine I am getting the result what I want but the problem is that while unprotecting the sheet it ask for password so I don't know how to provide a password.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.  If you want to unlock the excel sheet, you can right click on the sheet's name at left bottom, and select `Unprotect Sheet`.